# Convert SQL date to Javascript Format

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I am retrieving the date from SQL Database and the output for date I get is in format `/Date(1382612325023)/` [string], How can I convert it to readable date format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

`new Date(parseInt('/Date(1382612325023)/'.substr(6)));`

explanation :

You take the string you get from db , from index 6 . this will include `)/` at the end but parseInt will exclude it.
And `new Date` will work on this value.